# In android, how to print without printer plugins

Tags: android, printing

In android, can we add printer plugins inside application memory or there jar file inside asset folder, and try to call it from application, to create mobile printing.

As I find

**> Print Share Application** option only. Any other way without Google cloud or any cloud printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is working for me,I am passing pdf file to printer it is
>   printing!!
>
> class WifiPrint extends Activity {    TextView printer_name, gate_way,
>   printer_port;     int port = 9100;    WifiManager wifi = null;
>     android.net.DhcpInfo d;     String gateway_ip = "";
>
> @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_print);       wifi = (WifiManager)
>   getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);       printer_name = (TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.textView1);         gate_way = (TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.textView2);         printer_port = (TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.textView3);
>             /*  de.lohndirekt.print.IppPrintService svc = new IppPrintService(printerURI);      InputStream stream = new
>   BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("image.epl"));        DocFlavor
>   flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;        Doc myDoc = new
>   SimpleDoc(stream, flavor, null);      DocPrintJob job =
>   svc.createPrintJob();         job.print(myDoc, null);*/
>
> }
>
> @Override   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         //
>   Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wifi_print, menu);         return true;
>     }
>
> public void wifisettings(View v) {      startActivityForResult(new
>   Intent(
>                 android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);    }
>
> public void connectSocket(View v) {
>                 /*Uri filepath=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pdfsample);         Toast.makeText(this, filepath.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         */      ClientThread clientThread = new
>   ClientThread("");         Thread clientstartThread = new
>   Thread(clientThread);         clientstartThread.start();  }
>
> public String intToIp(int i) {      return ((i & 0xFF) + "." + ((i >> 8)
>   & 0xFF) + "." + ((i >> 16) & 0xFF)
>                 + "." + ((i >> 24) & 0xFF));    }
>
> @Override   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
>   resultCode, Intent data) {        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> ```
>   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      if
> ```
>
> (requestCode == 0) {          WifiInfo wifiinfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
>             d = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
>
> ```
>       printer_name.setText("Name:" + wifiinfo.getSSID());             gateway_ip =
> ```
>
> intToIp(d.gateway);           gate_way.setText("Printer Ip:" + gateway_ip);
>             printer_port.setText("Port:" + port);
>
> ```
>   }   }
> ```
>
> public File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
>
> ```
>  try{
>     File f = new File("/sdcard/testpdf.pdf");
>     OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
>     byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
>     int length = 0;
>
>     while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
>       outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
>     }
>
>     outputStream.close();
>     inputStream.close();
>
>     return f;
>  }catch (IOException e) {
>        //Logging exception
>  }
>
>  return null;     }
> ```
>
> class ClientThread implements Runnable {        String filepath = "";
>         BufferedInputStream bis = null;         FileInputStream fis;
>
> ```
>   Socket socket;
>
>   public ClientThread(String filename) {          filepath = filename;        }
>
>   @Override       public void run() {             // TODO Auto-generated method
> ```
>
> stub          try {
>                 InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pdfsample);
>                 createFileFromInputStream(in);
>                 File pdfFile = new File("/sdcard/testpdf.pdf");
>                 byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) pdfFile.length()];
>                 socket = new Socket(gateway_ip, port);
>                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void run() {
>                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                         if(socket.isConnected()){
>                             Toast.makeText(WifiPrint.this,
>                                     "Socket Connected",
>                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>                 fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
>                 bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
>                 bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
>                 OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
>                 os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
>                 os.flush();
>
> ```
>           if (bis != null) {
>               bis.close();
>               os.close();
>               socket.close();
>               fis.close();
>
>           }
>               } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>
>               @Override
>               public void run() {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                   Toast.makeText(WifiPrint.this,
>                           "UnHost Exceptions" + e.getMessage(),
>                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>               }
>           });             } catch (final IOException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>
>               @Override
>               public void run() {
>                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                   Toast.makeText(WifiPrint.this,
>                           "Io Exceptions" + e.getMessage(),
>                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>               }
>           });             } finally {
>           try {
>               if (bis != null) {
>                   bis.close();
>                   socket.close();
>                   fis.close();
>               }
>           } catch (final IOException e) {
>               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                   @Override
>                   public void run() {
>                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                       Toast.makeText(
>                               WifiPrint.this,
>                               "Io Exeption in Closing Socket"
>                                       + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
>                               .show();
>                   }
>               });
>           }           }       }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

In manifest file : just add:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
>
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!!

In Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, the framework provides services for printing images and documents directly from Android applications.

```
/**
 * To print image / photo
 */
private void printPhoto() {
    // Get a PrintHelper instance
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(this);
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    // get image from mipmap folder
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    // provide job name (which will be displayed in the print queue) and bitmap
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
}
```

Reference for print   [html and custom document](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)

Comment: how this will find printer?

Comment: How and android phone first connect with printers?

Comment: This code will gives you list of printer in your connection network. After choosing an printer they ask for print or not. This is an androids service for printer.

Comment: Have you tried the code? Connect your mobile and printer in same network and run the app.

Comment: No need to connect with Printer but your printer and device must be in same network connection. Have you tried the code????